# Changing fontSize for a class using Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="release-0">
  <p class="release-4"> Here is some text, add a class "done" to the parent div</p>
</div>

<div id="release-1">
  <p>remove the #release-1 div</p>
</div>

<h1>Change this text to finish release 2</h1>

<div id="release-3">
  <p class="release-4"> add CSS to this div</p>
</div>
```

How do I select all occurrences of class `.release-4` and change the `text-size` to `2em` using Javascript?

I've tried this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("release-4").style.fontSize = "2em";
```

but that doesn't work.

This does work:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("release-4")[0].style.fontSize = "2em";
```

but it only selects the first occurrence of `.release-4`.

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` returns a collection of nodes, you will need to iterate over them and apply the style to all of them if you wish to do it this way. It would be better to just add a class though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName()` method returns a collection of elements. You should loop through them and set the necessary font value for each element individually.

Comment: Is there any way to apply change to all elements without looping through?

Comment: @MuhammadQasim I do not think it is possible. Why do you avoid looping?
Or probably you should use CSS (i.e.setting class name on parent can affect all the child elements).

Answer (score 4):

You'll need to loop over the NodeList that is returned by `.getElementsByClassName()` and apply your change to each element.

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('release-4');

for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  var element = elements[i];
  element.style.fontSize = "2em";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `querySelectorAll` to select which class, then loop throught the returned collection, here is an example:

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll(".release-4");
for ( var i = 0; i < el.length; i ++ ) {
    el[i].style.fontSize = "2em";
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9px6LyLp/

Comment: `querySelectorAll` still returns a collection rather. So you still need to iterate. All you've done is swap `getElementsByClassName` for `querySelectorAll` and gained nothing.

Comment: ... and querySelectorAll is slower than getElementsByClassName. Also getElementsByClassName is lively updated but querySelectorAll don't, it only get the data when ordered.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
    .newClass {
  fontSize: 2em;
}
```

javascript

```
var el=document.getElementsByClassName('release-4');
for(var i=0, var tot=el.length; i < tot; i++){
    el[i].className = " release-4  newClass ";
}
```

to remove class newClass: same for loop and

```
el[i].className = " release-4 ";
```

to remove class release-4: same for loop and

```
el[i].className = " newClass ";
```

to remove class newClass you can also use

```
el[i].className = el[i].className.replace(" newClass ","");
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend adding a new class to each element instead of editing each style individually

```
.newClass {
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

I know your question is asking for `JavaScript`, but `JQuery` has a much quicker resolution.

```
//Add a class
$(".release-4").addClass('newClass');
//If you want to remove the existing class after
$(".release-4").addClass('release-4');
```

If you still want to set the styles manually you can do:

```
$(".release-4").css('font-size','2em');
```

JQuery loops through all instances of the class for you

Comment: @Radonirina: Don't radically change people's answers like that. Your edit not only changes the meaning of the answer but it's totally broken too.

Comment: Thanks for flagging that @squint